# Create Bookshelf.js models without connection and make connection in route files

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have `Bookshelf.js` models (a general model with `parse()` and `format()` functions and a model for each table that extends the general model) and routes that use these models. The database is `PostgreSQL`. But I have users in a `SQLite` database and each user has its own PostgreSQL connection options. I can retrieve the current user and expose its database connection options in the request, so every route knows how to connect to `PostgreSQL`. But how can I connect and use my `Bookshelf.js` models in a route? This is an example of what I am trying to do in a routes file:

```
var express = require('express'),
knex = require('knex'),

// This should be the file that exposes all models.
// Every model exposed, extends the general model.
// But it already requires a connection when init Bookshelf.js...
dataBookshelf = require('../models'),

router = express.Router();

router.get('/items/:id',function(req,res,next) {

    // In req.db I have PostgreSQL connection options for the current user.
    var connection = req.db;

    // Make a connection to PostgreSQL.
    var db = dataBookshelf(knex(connection));

    // Use Items model.
    var Items = db.Items;

    Items.read(req.params.id).then(function(item) {
        res.json(item);
    }).catch(Items.NotFoundError,function() {
        var err = new Error('Item not found.');
        res.status(400).json(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

If there is another way to save the current user connection options `globally` and to use them in the module that exposes `Bookshelf.js` instance, instead of passing them in the request, it should be better and safer.

Comment: Pass the user id instead of the `db` connection options in the route and look for that in the sqlite database? Or in your login action just save the connection option in the session object or something like that.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is I have a general model and more specialized models that extend the general model. How can I create these models in separate modules and require them in route files if I have not initialized Bookshelf (and Knex) yet?

Comment: Oh I see. I guess you'll have to add some kind of method to your `'../models'` file that would setup a connection and reload all of the models each time it's called. This would be easier to do if you could just use Knex and Bookshelf without a database connection, but that is currently not possible.

Comment: You are right. This is a BIG problem, because we have a lot of customers, each with its own database. And also some customers have two or three databases in different sites with different data. Since our software requires login, I am thinking to save user db data in a file or using another method to store them...